# Why is my terminal output not identical when running a yarn script vs its bash equivalent?

Tags: docker, terminal, yarnpkg, tty

**NOTE: I've added updates in order, just keep reading, thanks. :) **

I've been very curious about this -- please see this screenshot of me running:

- `ls -lah build`, and
- `yarn run assets`, which runs `ls -lah build`.

[image: bash_vs_yarn]

Let me start by saying that this is a WIP build in webpack, so no need to tell me that a 31M bundle is less than optimal. :)

But why do I get the colors and the more detailed font with the native command and not when `yarn` executes the command? It may be relevant: this screen shot is:
 - Windows 10
 - Webstorm terminal
 - logged in to a docker container running Ubuntu 14.4

Thanks! :)

** UPDATE: --color=always restores color **
As [@Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) suggested, adding `--color=always` in the yarn script preserved the formatting:

[image: color_always]

If anyone has some specialized knowledge to share about what's going on here, I'm in the market to hear it! Thanks!

Comment: This generally means that `yarn` (whatever it is) is capturing the output and then printing it itself. `ls --color=auto` (default in many places) checks whether its output is going direct to a TTY, and only turns on color if it is; if that output is being captured by another program, stdout will be a FIFO, and `istty()` will be false.

Comment: See if `ls --color=always` (which, unlike `--color=auto`, ignores the check)  behaves differently.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I love this answer -- but I don't understand 75% of it! :) 

I come from web development and I'm no slouch on the terminal, but would you be willing to expand on your answer, assuming that I know very little about what goes on with std -in -out -err -whatever?

Comment: I've tried to write up an answer that provides as much background as I reasonably can -- if you need more, could you ask specific questions?

Comment: You were just faster than me, my apologies! You have answered my question and given me a bunch of info in addition -- thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short(ish) answer: What's actually going on?

*The below answer assumes the GNU implementation of `ls`*.

There are a few possibilities at play:

- Your interactive terminal's options may be modified by a shell alias. Output from `type ls` will indicate whether this is true.
- You may have `ls --color=auto` enabled, either via an alias or via an equivalent environment variable; regardless, this checks whether it's writing directly to a TTY, and only enables color if so.

If output is *not* direct to a TTY (for instance, if output is being captured by `yarn` before it's printed), `ls --color=auto` will not colorize.

To fix this, you can explicitly pass `ls --color=always`, or its equivalent, simply `ls --color`. This covers both cases: If you had an alias in use passing `--color=auto` on your behalf, passing it explicitly means you no longer need the alias. By contrast, if `yarn` is capturing content rather than passing it straight to the TTY, then `--color=always` tells `ls` to ignore `isatty()` returning false and colorize anyhow.

---

#### Background on what the above means:

A "TTY" is, effectively, a terminal. It provides bells and whistles (*literally*, for the bells) specialized for providing a device that a user is actually typing at. This means it has control sequences for inspecting and modifying cursor location, and -- pertinently for our purposes -- for changing the color with which output is rendered.

A "FIFO" is a pipe -- it moves characters from point A to point B, first-in, first-out. In the case of `prog-one | prog-two`, the thing that connects those two is a FIFO. It just moves characters, and has no concept of cursor location or colorization or anything else.

If `ls` tried to put color sequences in its output when that output is intended for any destination other than a terminal, those sequences wouldn't make any sense -- indeed, the very *format* in which colorization markers need to be printed is determined by the `TERM` variable specifying the currently active terminal type.

If you run `ls --color`, then, you're promising `ls` that its output *really will* be rendered by a terminal, or (at least) otherwise something that understands the color sequences appropriate to the currently configured `TERM`.

Comment: This has significantly increased my understanding of what's going on at this terminal level -- and why I'm seeing a lot of wacky `[0E3m%]` kind of characters in a bunch of my logs, since I'm assuming they're color sequences being written to a file and not a TTY!

Awesome, amazing, thanks a million!